# Why are MOSFETs so expensive?

Tags: mosfet

I know EE.SE isn't about economics, but the fact that a typical MOSFET can cost as much as a microprocessor, raises the question of why?  Are they that difficult to make?

Comment: You should at least give an example of what you are comparing. In our designs the FETs are all much cheaper than a microcontroller. So your typical FET seems to be a completely different thing than my typical FET.

Comment: Also price does not always reflect how difficult it is to produce something. There's supply and demand. Different types of cost.

Comment: Also: a microprocessor can contain 100 thousands of very typical MOSFETs. So you have to be more specific. What do you mean exactly by typical MOFSET?

Comment: You need to stop buying MOSFETs one by one.

Comment: You could also ask: Why are microprocessors so cheap?

Comment: I have a ring on my finger which has zero FETs in it, and it still costs like a CPU. So perhaps there's no direct relationship between the cost of something and the number of MOSFETs in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by 'typical' MOSFET, but prices of many types of components can vary. It also depends on what you class as 'expensive'

You can get some very high priced components as well as very low priced ones. It depends on a few things (from my experience) such as package, durability, accuracy, how many you purchase, operating temp, application and even 'special features'. Take for example this MOSFET; the [IXFB100N50Q3](http://uk.farnell.com/ixys-semiconductor/ixfb100n50q3/mosfet-n-ch-650v-100a-plus264/dp/2674743). Pretty unremarkable really when you look at the stats compared to most, but this one costs £23 for 1!! Now *that* is pricey! If you look at the power dissipation though, you can see that it has a Pd of 1.56kW which is huge. For some applications it is definitely worth that money! But, even though it is £23 for one, if you bought over 1000, they are £16 each.

Now for another MOSFET, on the other end of the scale, the [2N7002](http://uk.farnell.com/on-semiconductor/2n7002lt3g/n-channel-mosfet-60v-115ma-sot/dp/1764537) which I have personally used alot, because it does the job I need it to, and it is less that 10p!! Buying over 1000 of these at a time makes them almost 1p each. That for me is a 'typical' MOSFET and I would not call that expensive!

Now for microcontrollers.... These can really vary in price, from very basic 8-bit microcontrollers like the [PIC16F1824](http://uk.farnell.com/microchip/pic16f1824-i-sl/mcu-8bit-pic16-32mhz-soic-14/dp/1814945) which is around £1 to but, or if you get them in bulk, about 76p!

On the other end of the scale, an all-singing, all dancing, full-of-features such as the [ADUCM310BBCZ](http://uk.farnell.com/analog-devices/aducm310bbcz/mcu-32bit-cortex-m3-80mhz-cspbga/dp/2566055) costs a whopping £42.50 each! Or again, bring the price down to £35 by buying in bulk.

So, you can't really make a claim that 'MOSFETS are expensive', you just need to shop around and look through datasheets to find one that is in your price range and suits you.

**NOTE:** All I did was searched MOSFETS and MCUs on Farnell and sort by price to get this data. I am sure some more experienced people can come up with a more in-depth reasoning that I can as to why prices vary so much, but I hope these practical examples will be a good starting point.

Comment: I'm paying €0,03 for placing each smd component with pick and place. This makes placing and soldering the 2N7002 more expensive than the component.